# CAGradientLayer not being applied to whole screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, cagradientlayer

I am trying to apply a gradient layer to a screen but annoyingly the layer only takes up half of the screen.

I think the issue seems to come from this problem here:

`descriptionTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true`

This is my first time working with programmatic constraints so it's a bit tricky for me to see where the problem lies.

[Here is an image of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfIbp.png)

**Here is the code below**

```
class OBP1VC: UIViewController {

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let caGradient = CAGradientLayer()
        caGradient.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        caGradient.colors = [Colours.brightGreen.cgColor, Colours.midBlue.cgColor]
        caGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        caGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        return caGradient
    }()

    let bearImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "br_flag"))
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

    let descriptionTextView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "Hello\n\nWelcome to the new\n\nHome Healthcare"
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.textAlignment = .center
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        textView.font = UIFont(name: Fonts.avenirBlack, size: 20.0)
        return textView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.addSubview(bearImageView)
        view.addSubview(descriptionTextView)

        setupLayout()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }

    private func setupLayout() {

        bearImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        bearImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        bearImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        bearImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

        descriptionTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        descriptionTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        descriptionTextView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        descriptionTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: if i do that the text doesn't appear at all

Comment: clear background color of descriptionTextView -         descriptionTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

Comment: just try calling  view.layoutIfNeeded() after setting gradient layer...
in my case this solved problem, i was facing this issue too..

Comment: @Pankaj Thanks, setting the textview color to clear solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In above code Background color of textView covered gradient layout, so clearing it will make gradient visible**

Your setupLayout method should look like this -

```
private func setupLayout() {

        bearImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        bearImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        bearImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        bearImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        bearImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

        descriptionTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        descriptionTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        descriptionTextView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        descriptionTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        descriptionTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
```

Comment: Please provide what issue you solve in above answer so user can understand issue also

Comment: Background color of textView covered gradient layout, so clearing it will make gradient visible.

Answer (score 0):

add this class to your project and give your view this class in storyboard and you can also set gradient colors and positions and can see in storyboard its for two color gradient have a look...

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var startColor:   UIColor = .black { didSet { updateColors() }}
    @IBInspectable var endColor:     UIColor = .white { didSet { updateColors() }}
    @IBInspectable var startLocation: Double =   0.05 { didSet { updateLocations() }}
    @IBInspectable var endLocation:   Double =   0.95 { didSet { updateLocations() }}
    @IBInspectable var horizontalMode:  Bool =  false { didSet { updatePoints() }}
    @IBInspectable var diagonalMode:    Bool =  false { didSet { updatePoints() }}

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { return layer as! CAGradientLayer }

    func updatePoints() {
        if horizontalMode {
            gradientLayer.startPoint = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0) : CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
            gradientLayer.endPoint   = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1) : CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        } else {
            gradientLayer.startPoint = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) : CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint   = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1) : CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        }
    }
    func updateLocations() {
        gradientLayer.locations = [startLocation as NSNumber, endLocation as NSNumber]
    }
    func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors    = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePoints()
        updateLocations()
        updateColors()
    }
}
```